# Proving a sequence in a power series ring is regular

Tags: ring-theory, commutative-algebra

I'm reading a paper where in one of the lemmas, the authors prove that a sequence of elements $r_1,\ldots, r_7$ in the power series ring $\mathcal{O}[[X_1,\ldots,X_6]]$ is a regular sequence (here $\mathcal{O}$ is the ring of integers in some finite extension of $\mathbb{Q}_p$ for $p$ an odd prime). The authors claim that it suffices to show the quotient $$\mathcal{O}[[X_1,\ldots,X_6]]/(r_1,\ldots,r_7)$$
is finite, and this is where I am confused. I discussed this with the authors and they seemed to agree that the important thing here is that a finite ring has dimension $0$. I know that for a Noetherian local ring $A$, we have $\dim A/(x) = \dim A - 1$ when $x$ is not a zero-divisor. However, the converse is what we would want here and I don't believe this is true in general. Showing that the above quotient is finite shows that if one looks at the successive quotients $\mathcal{O}[[X_1,\ldots,X_6]]/(r_1,\ldots,r_k)$ for $k \leq 7$, the dimension goes down by $1$ at each stage as would occur if the sequence was regular. However, I don't see how it quite shows that $r_k$ is not a zero divisor in $\mathcal{O}[[X_1,\ldots,X_6]]/(r_1,\ldots,r_{k-1})$.

Comment: Nice question. I'm a little rusty on my commutative algebra, but I believe your power series ring is equidimensional CM, in which case I think this answer should address your question: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1786560/73817. (If it does, let me know and I'll mark this question a duplicate.)

Comment: First of all, instead of telling us a long story you could give a reference. At least for me this would be more helpful. Second, the ring is Cohen-Macaulay, and a system of parameters in a CM local ring is a regular sequence. Now we have to figure out if $r_i$ are contained in a maximal ideal in order to localize at it. So please give us a reference to see all the details.